# How to get x next items from a list with a specific class constraint

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am having a list of different types of objects let's call them Clauses

```
List<Clause> clauses = new ArrayList<Clause>();
```

In each Clause I want to have a sublist of clauses called forwardClauses

I would like for each of the clauses to put in its forwardClauses a given x number of clauses that are after it filtering out clauses that are instanceof WeirdClause. I also don't care of the forwardClauses that WeirdClauses have.

So 
`NormalClause extends Clause` and
`WeirdClause extends Clause`

with a list

```
[
NormalClause(uuid=1), 
NormalClause(uuid=2), 
NormalClause(uuid=3), 
WeirdClause(uuid=4), 
NormalClause(uuid=5)
]
```

should give me for the first one if x=2 (= 2 clauses forward)

```
uuid=1
forwardClauses = [NormalClause(uuid=2), NormalClause(uuid=3)]

uuid=2
forwardClauses = [NormalClause(uuid=3), NormalClause(uuid=5)]

uuid=3
forwardClauses = [NormalClause(uuid=5)]

uuid=4
forwardClauses = []

uuid=5
forwardClauses = []
```

So this is my first implementation after I asked the question (haven't checked it):

```
public static void setForwardClauses(List<Clause> clauses, int forwardClausesNum) {
    for (int i = 0; i< clauses.size(); i++){
        Clause clause = clauses.get(i);
        if(clause instanceof WeirdClause){
            continue;
        }
        int forwardClausesToGo = forwardClausesNum;
        for(int j = i+1; j < clauses.size(); j++){
            Clause forwardClause = clauses.get(j);  
            if(forwardClausesToGo > 0 && !(forwardClause instanceof WeirdClause)){
                clause.addForwardClause(forwardClause);
                forwardClausesToGo--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit: Improved version O(N) based on nukie's answer leveraging O(1) list.get(i)**

```
    private void lookForwardClauses(List<Clause clauses, int forwardClausesNum) {
        for (int i = 0; i< clauses.size(); i++){
            Clause clause = clauses.get(i);
            if(clause instanceof InnerText){
                continue;
            }
            int forwardClausesToGo = forwardClausesNum;
            int j = 1;
            while(i+j < clauses.size() && forwardClausesToGo > 0) {
                Clause forwardClause = clauses.get(i+j);
                if(!(forwardClause instanceof WeirdClause)){
                    clause.addForwardClause(forwardClause);
                    forwardClausesToGo--;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Whatever comes to my head is O(N^2) and the approach of keeping pointers for the next elements would be trivial but here they have to be equal to forwardClausesNum and on top of that some elements are not counted so pointers I believe wouldn't work.

Any help is appreciated if there is a more performant alternative I could take :) Thanks

Comment: Well I didn't ask for specific code - which I might if needed with a bounty. But everything that comes to mind is with O(N^2) complexity. I have thought of having pointers to keep track of next elements and that would have been trivial, but the forwardNum is dynamic and some of the elements will have to be filtered out

Comment: I will send what I have soon

Comment: @marstran I sent what I have done - it is not checked yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can try it that way:

```
public static void setForwardClauses(List<Clause> clauses, int forwardClausesNum) {
   int counter=0;
   Clause current = clauses.get(counter);
   //skip leading WeirdClauses
   do {
     counter++;         
   } while (current instanceOf WeirdClause);

   if (current instanceOf WeirdClause)
     return;
   int group = 0;
   for (counter = counter + 1; counter < clauses.size();counter++){
     if (clauses.get(counter) instanceOf WeirdClause)
       continue;
     if (group == forwardClausesNum) {
       current = clauses.get(current);
       group = 0;
     } else {
       current.forwardClauses.add(clauses.get(counter));
       group++;
     }
   }
}
```

Since you didn't put a return value to your function I wrote this sample as a side-effect function. But of course you can put results in some other collection.

Comment: Thanks! wouldn't that stop counting (count++) when it finds WeirdClause - I just want to skip them. 
This seems to have time complexity of O(N) which would be ideal! . Please check my code for the expected behavior.

Comment: yes, this implementation will skip WeirdClauses. continue statement just routing the cycle to next iteration without execution of reminding code in loop block. I think our solutions is pretty much the same.

Comment: oh yeah list.get(i) should be O(1) since this is an arrayList

Comment: hmmm.... actually, there is not much sense to skip initial WeirdClauses )
I tink this was a result of my mind-flow)

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a good way to do it:

1. Get the tail of the list (all elements except the first one)
2. Set the forward clauses of the first element by limiting the tail with `forwardClausesNum`.
3. Call the function recursively with the tail.
4. If the list is empty, you're done.

Edit:
If you're using Java 8, I think this might solve your problem. It may be done more efficiently though, but unless performance is a really big problem, this should be sufficient.

```
public static void setForwardClauses(List<Clause> clauses, int num) {
    List<Clause> normalClauses = 
           clauses.stream()
                  .filter(c -> !(c instanceof WeirdClause))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

    recSetForwardClauses(normalClauses);
}

private static void recSetForwardClauses(List<Clause> clauses, int num) {
    if(clauses.isEmpty()) return;

    List<Clause> tail = 
           clauses.stream().skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Clause> limited =
           tail.stream().limit(num).collect(Collectors.toList());      

    clauses.get(0).setForwardClauses(limited);

    recSetForwardClauses(tail);
}
```

Comment: And of course, remove the `WeirdClause`s when adding them to the forward clauses. Also, skip setting the forwardClauses when the first element is a `WeirdClause`.

Comment: Thanks! that is an interesting approach using recursion - what is the space and time complexity of this approach? Is it better than the iterative approach in any way?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this approach is O(n) in both time and space complexity. You can use the `sublist`-method on `List` so that you don't have to iterate through the elements when you get the tail and when you limit the tail. However, be aware that this method creates a view over the original list. This means that if you mutate the original list, then all the sublists will also be mutated.

Comment: You may also want to filter out all `WeirdClause`s before you call the method, so you don't have to "refilter" the list all the time.

Comment: I still need the WeirdClauses in the initial list though :)

Comment: Yes, but you can just create a new list with all the NormalClauses before calling the method. You don't have to touch your original list.